# dtype does not provide enough data type precision. Alternatives?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dtype

I am trying to check the formats of columns in a number of excel files (.xlsx) to see if they match.
To do so, I am using the function dtype of pandas.
The problem is that it returns the same data type (datetime64[ns]) for two different date formats within 'Date'.

What are the alternatives of this function to have more precision?

```
#Import pandas
import pandas as pd

#Read MyFile and store in dataframe df1
df1=pd.read_excel(MyFile,sheetname=0,header=0,index_col=False,keep_default_na=False)

#Print the data type of the column MyColumnName
print(df1[str(MyColumnName)].dtype)
```

I would like to have more accuracy on the data type information to be able to flag differences between spreadsheets.

Comment: Check the date format, not the datatype. Pandas is very flexible when it comes to interpreting dates.

Comment: What do you mean by more accuracy?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah  I would like to know if the date is on the format '2019-08-17' or '17/08/2018' , for example.